# Can squid run behind nginx?

Tags: nginx, squid

I'm trying to run a squid server behind nginx.
I configured nginx like this:

```
server {
    listen     8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:3128;
        proxy_set_header Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Then I set my http network proxy to:

```
my-nginx-server-address:8080
```

So when I try to view the Google homepage, the nginx will get the request:

```
Get http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

However when nginx pass the request to squid it will change the request_uri to

```
/
```

So squid won't work.
Is there any way I can set the request_uri back to http://www.google.com then pass it to squid? Or any other ways I can run squid behind nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Try proxy_set_header Request-URI $request_uri;

In reply to your comment, you may also prefer to add:

`upstream _squid {
    server localhost:3128;
}
server {
...
    proxy_pass http://_squid/$host$uri;
}`

Comment: I tried this myself and I couldn't figure out how to get squid to pay attention to this Request-URI header.  Maybe this is something not supported in the latest version of squid?  I can't even find any documentation mentioning this header.