# Reverse proxy from nginx to squid

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid, http-proxy

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029129/can-squid-run-behind-nginx), I am trying to host a squid proxy behind nginx:

`example.com` - the main site

`relay.example.com` - the squid server.

So far, when I try to use the squid proxy, it will complain about accessing an illegal page, for example, if I try to access `http://www.google.com`, I get an Invalid URL error saying that the URL `/http://www.google.com` (note the preceding /). Could anyone suggest why this is happening, or a fix for nginx or perhaps in the squid config?

```
upstream @squid {
    server localhost:3128;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name relay.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://@squid/$scheme://$host$uri;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Request-URI $request_uri;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

[https://imgur.com/qtgrZI9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u61Lv.png)

The log from squid gives:

```
1423083723.857      0 127.0.0.1 NONE/400 3530 GET /http://www.google.com/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

And nginx for the same request:

```
12.34.56.78 - - [04/Feb/2015:16:02:03 -0500] "GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1" 400 3183 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0" "-"
```

Comment: did you solve this problem?I encounter the same issue now

Comment: no, still unsolved unfortunately :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in nginx:

```
proxy_pass http://@squid;
```

in squid:

```
http_port 3128 vhost
```

and that's all you need for fix this https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FSB8.jpg error

Comment: actually you also need to allow direct forwarding, like so: 
`http_port 3128 vhost allow-direct`

(squid 4.6-1+deb10u1)

Comment: Also, `vhost` is deprecated in new squid versions, I'm using `accel` insted

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, solved it by setting squid to run in transparent mode, like this:

```
http_port 3128 transparent
```

Comment: 'tranasparent' is only for NAT routing not nginx reverse proxy.